# xml into access from FRED database?

Tags: xml, ms-access

I'm trying to insert data from the St. Louis Feds database of economic-data into MS Access. I'm a student, and this is just something that I was wondering; thought it would be a good way to learn about databases. Unfortunately, it seems like the XML format that the Fed uses isn't recognized by Access: it fails to populate the table even though it does import the XML file. Not sure if anyone has any experience with this, but I thought I'd ask nonetheless. 
Apologize if this is the wrong forum for this question; figured since all the Fed's information is public it was ok.

You'll need an free API-key, but let's move beyond that. The data comes in this xml format:

```
 <observations realtime_start="2013-02-08" realtime_end="2013-02-08"  
 observation_start="1776-07-04" observation_end="9999-12-31" units="lin"   
 output_type="2" file_type="xml" order_by="observation_date" sort_order="asc" 
 count="792" offset="0"        limit="100000">
  <observation date="1947-01-01" CPIAUCSL_20130208="21.48"/>
  <observation date="1947-02-01" CPIAUCSL_20130208="21.62"/>
  <observation date="1947-03-01" CPIAUCSL_20130208="22.0"/>
  </observations>
```

So that's basically an example of the data-set. Now, if I try to enter that into Access via the XML-link, it basically creates a Table with one Column whose head is Observations; it does NOT, however, populate the table with Dates and Values? Any help is appreciated.